# DFS Maze Solver returns false when correct

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search, maze, recursive-backtracking

I'm currently working on a little maze solver project to get a better grasp of algorithms like depth-first search. It works in that turns the current position to 2, then checks one of the positions(up, down, left or right) if it's a 0(path) and it will move forward until it's surrounded by cells are 1s(walls) then it's a dead end and it backtracks.

However my maze solver strangely enough keeps returning false, even when it has found its way to the number 3(the end). So I have two questions, what is causing it to return false and what can be changed in the solver so that only the shortest path will have the number 2(i.e when it backtracks it'll turn the dead end path into something else)?

Thanks in advance!

Maze solver

```
public class DFS {
    
    private int[][] maze;
    
    public DFS(int[][] maze) {
        
        this.maze = maze;
    }
    
    // Solves given maze recursively, input starting position in maze.
    public boolean solve(int x, int y) {
        
        maze[x][y] = 2;
        
        // 3 is the cell the algorithm is supposed to find.
        if (maze[x][y] == 3) {
            return true;
        }
        
        // Looks up.
        if (x > 0 && maze[x-1][y] == 0  && solve (x-1, y) ) {
            maze[x][y] = 2;
            return true;
        }
        // Looks down
        if (x < maze.length && maze[x+1][y] == 0  && solve (x+1, y) ) {
            maze[x][y] = 2;
            return true;
        }
        // Looks right.
        if (y < maze.length && maze[x][y+1] == 0  && solve (x, y+1) ) {
            maze[x][y] = 2;
            return true;
        }
        // Looks left.
        if (y > 0 && maze[x][y-1] == 0  && solve (x, y-1) ) {
            maze[x][y] = 2;
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

Hardcoded maze

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestMazeDFS {
    private static int[][] maze = {
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},        
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1},
        };
    
    public int[][] getMaze(){
        
        return this.maze;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        DFS dfs = new DFS(maze);
        boolean test = dfs.solve(1, 1);
        System.out.println(test);
        
    }
}
```

Image of the solution when printed.
[image: Solved Maze]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lWo3.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look tells me you're doing this wrong:

```
        maze[x][y] = 2;
        
        // 3 is the cell the algorithm is supposed to find.
        if (maze[x][y] == 3) { // <-- It will never be 3
            return true;
        }
```

Also in every if-check: `if (x > 0 && maze[x-1][y] == 0  && solve (x-1, y) ) {`, you're only visiting neighbors with value `0`. So for obvious reasons, you'll never visit a cell with value `3`. The if-check should be something like: `if (x > 0 && (maze[x-1][y] == 0 || maze[x-1][y] == 3)  && solve (x-1, y) ) {`

And do note that when backtracking, you need to revert the state back to the original state. That is, `maze[x][y]` should have the original value when you're returning false.

Maybe try this?

```
    public boolean solve(int x, int y) {
        // 3 is the cell the algorithm is supposed to find.
        if (maze[x][y] == 3) {
            maze[x][y] = 2;
            return true;
        }

        int orig = maze[x][y];
        maze[x][y] = 2;
        
        // Looks up.
        if (x > 0 && (maze[x-1][y] == 0 || maze[x-1][y] == 3)  && solve (x-1, y) ) {
            //maze[x][y] = 2;
            return true;
        }
        // Looks down
        if (x < maze.length && (maze[x+1][y] == 0 || maze[x+1][y] == 3)  && solve (x+1, y) ) {
            //maze[x][y] = 2;
            return true;
        }
        // Looks right.
        if (y < maze.length && (maze[x][y+1] == 0 || maze[x][y+1] == 3)  && solve (x, y+1) ) {
            //maze[x][y] = 2;
            return true;
        }
        // Looks left.
        if (y > 0 && (maze[x][y-1] == 0 || maze[x][y-1] == 3)  && solve (x, y-1) ) {
            //maze[x][y] = 2;
            return true;
        }

        maze[x][y] = orig;
        return false;
    }
```

Working solution: https://onlinegdb.com/ryxoPKgCaw

Comment: It backtracks correctly and reverts to the original state but not it doesn't finish when it reaches the end, instead when it's at the next last cell right above the number 3(the) end it just backtracks all the way back to the end and returns false.

Comment: @Codexing Sorry, the issue was that in the if-check we were only visiting neighbors with value 0. We need to visit neighbor with value 3 as well :) I've edited the code and also added a working example.

Comment: Hi again, I saw similar maze solvers but they were called BFS instead of DFS and I got confused. Isn't my maze solver using DFS and if it's not then why? Again thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Codexing Yes, your maze solver uses DFS. Moreover, I don't think BFS is a good way to solve such problems unless you're looking for the shortest path.